# Need to know ip address through my viber login

Tags: gmail

My laptop has been stolen and viber is installed there, the thief has acceesed my viber . can i check the ip address associated with my viber so that i can trace the location of my laptop.

other my viber account is linked with my gmail account. can i show my viber login activity/ipaddress/location on gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your IP activities from gmail too, go to the gmail homepage, scroll down and look for *last account activity: some time ago*, under that line there is a link to *details*
there you can see from where your Google account has been accessed, hopefully you can retrieve your laptop

Good luck :D